# Embedded Servlet 3.0 container to use ServletContainerInitializer instead of web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

From the way I understand it, 3.0 servlet containers are supposed to scan the classpath for implementations of the ServletContainerInitializer interface (ie. [springs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html)). Subsequently this should call the onStartup method of [WebApplicationInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) implementations.

Great. Awesome.

Now I want to build a jar file that will startup an embedded 3.0 servlet container (jetty 8 or tomcat 7) and do just that. I see plenty of examples on how to build a war file to do so. But how do I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to build a .war file, you'll need call `WebApplicationInitializer`'s `onStartup(ServletContext)` yourself. How you get the servlet context is going to be specific to the container you use.

In Tomcat:

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
// skipping a few steps
Context ctx = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, baseDir);
ServletContext sc = ctx.getServletContext();
```